# Basic camera calibration without checkerboard

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

## The problem

I don't have access to the camera that was taking pictures below. You can find the source video here https://youtu.be/C7hS3enWh94?t=343

I would like to perform coarse camera calibration using only the information I have in the video frames (which is a road line that supposed to be straight but looks rounded in the images and luckily covers most of the sensor area over time).

## What I need

I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to find coarse camera distortion parameters because I think there is no way to accurately estimate camera calibration parameters using only available information.

I'm out of ideas on how to progress with this problem. My idea is too complicated and would take much effort to implement with low guarantee that it would actually work. So the question I have is actually more of a brainstorm on hypothetical approaches to solving this problem.

## P.S.

I thought it should be possible to implement Hough transform to look for circle curvature (circle radius that would accommodate most pixels) but the curvature we're looking at would definitely result with very large radius. In turn it might not form perfect circle and rather be an ellipse because of imperfect 90 degrees angle at which camera looks down to road. This complicates Hough Transform implementation significantly.

Another way I was thinking was to use random search algorithms such as genetic algorithm to fiddle distortion + scale + rotation + translation parameters that would result with one image being fit on top of another image perfectly. But again it would take me much time to complete anything like this.

Any better ideas from OpenCV gurus out there?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the paper "straight lines have to be straight"

Comment: If your looking for genetic algorithms you could use https://github.com/dadukhankevin/Finch.